# Python: What is the best structure that allows functions to access information across calls

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm currently writing an agent function that is designed to compete in competition and will get called every turn to perform a series of moves. There is data that I'd like to save between turns (calls of the function).

My question is what is the best way to store this data so that my function can access it between calls without having to recompute it every call. I was thinking about making a global class object that would store everything I needed, but suspected there might be other ways.

To give an example, let's say I want to store a long list that took a bit of time to compute inside that function, where can I put/store that list so that I can access it again the next time the function is called, without having to recompute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two straightforward solutions, if I understand the question correctly. You can use a closure--an inner function--so you can do your preprocessing of your data and return a function that has access to it in its scope.

Here, with a rather silly example of an accumulated sum that you can initialise when you create the closure:

```py
def make_acc_sum(init_elements):
    # initial preprocessing
    s = sum(init_elements)

    # function that knows the preprocessed data
    def acc_sum(new_val):
        nonlocal s
        s += new_val
        return s

    return acc_sum


ac = make_acc_sum([1, 2, 3])
for i in range(5):
    print(ac(i))
```

This is a fine technique in many applications, when you don't want to do too much with the data in the enclosing scope. If you just want to access it when invoking a function and nothing more, it can handle your needs.

If you want your "function" to support more general manipulation of your pre-processed data, you can turn it into an object. Objects from a class that implements `__call__` can be called just as functions can:

```py
class acc_sum:
    def __init__(self, init_elements):
        # initial preprocessing
        self.s = sum(init_elements)

    def __call__(self, new_val):
        # function that knows the preprocessed data
        self.s += new_val
        return self.s


ac = acc_sum([1, 2, 3])
for i in range(5):
    print(ac(i))
```

but this version of `ac` is still an object that can have attributes and additional methods on it, so you can do more with it than you can with a plain closure (even though the example doesn't exploit that).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be onto the right track. Why not create an object class, make instances of it to store different 'save data', and see how it goes?

```
class saveFile:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

def main():
    data = something.compute() #whatever that took a bit of time to compute...
    #create an instance of a saveFile class object
    file_1 = saveFile(data)
    #to recall the data in the form of file_1.data
    print(file_1.data)
```